$2f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-c), x>0$
I'm trying to solve the functional equation $2f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-c), x>0$, where $c\in(0,1)$ is a fixed constant, under the condition that:
1). $f$ restricted to $(-\infty,0] $ is zero
2). $f$ is non-decreasing with $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=1$
I understand that if I had the same equation $2f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1/2)$ for all $ x\in \mathbb{R}$ and assuming continuity, then the general solution would be $f(x)=c_1+c_2a^x$, where $a=(3-\sqrt{5})/2$ is the non-trivial solution to $a+1/\sqrt{a}=2$. However, by requiring $f=0$ on the negative axis, this nice general solution is messed up. So I am expecting something like a series to come up as the solution to my question, and any other closed-form formulas are also welcome.
Edit I originally asked this question with $c=\frac{1}{2}$, but as pointed out by Christophe Leuridan, this case is very special because the possible values of $S_n$ are just integers an half-integers, and then $S^x_n>0$ if and only if $S^{\lceil 2x\rceil /2}_n>0$, so that one may assume without loss of generality that $x\in\frac{1}{2} \mathbb N$ and then apply a standard martingale argument (or just use the general solution formula above with conditions 1) and 2)) to get $f(x)= 1-a^x$ for $x\in\frac{1}{2} \mathbb N$. Hence $f(x)= 1-a^{\lceil 2x\rceil /2}$ for $x>0$. Of course one would expect similar staircase functions to appear as solutions to other rational numbers $c$ of the form $\frac{1}{n}$. So now the interesting case is when $c$ is either a rational number of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ with $m>1$ or $c$ is an irrational number.
The motivation for this problem is that I'm trying to compute the probability where a (step-length) biased random walk never cross the origin: let $S^x_n=x+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i=1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $X_i=-\frac{1}{2}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Then denote
\begin{equation}
f(x):= \mathbb{P} (\forall n\geq 0, S_n^x>0).
\end{equation}
By conditioning on the first step, we obtain $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+1)+f(x-1/2))$ with the boundary condition $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. And it's clear from definition that $f$ is non-decreasing. To see why $f(x)$ converges to 1 when $x$ goes to infinity, one way is to note that by letting $Y_i=\operatorname{sign}(X_i)$ (that is, $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{|X_i|}$), we have
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i>-\frac{n}{3}-\frac{4x}{3}\right).
\end{equation}
And now that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is a simple random walk, we can apply the standard technique of splitting between $n<N$ and $n>N$. Then use $x\to+\infty$ in the $n<N$ regime, and use the law of iterated logarithm in the $n>N$ regime.
Motivation of motivation (really not useful for anything, but this is how I came across this question): It is obvious that if a gambler participates in a game where they start with $x$ bucks and at each round, flip a fair coin to decide whether they win 1 buck or lose 1 buck, then there is a chance (namely, $1/2^x$) that the gambler loses straight to 0 bucks and is not permitted to play anymore.
However, if the rule is that when they flip the coin and get the head, their money is doubled, and if if they get tail they lose half of their money, then there is no longer an absorption state and by the recurrence property of 1-d simple random walk, they almost surely can wait long enough to win any desired amount of money.
In this regard, casinos will never agree to play this game with gamblers. Instead, a casino might propose to play by the following rule: if coin head is obtained, then double the money of gambler, if coin tail is obtained, then gambler loses $\frac{3}{4}$ of their money. So if the gambler initially had $4^{-x}$ buck, then at round $n$, the gambler is left with $4^{-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-x}$ bucks, where $X_i$ is $1$ or $-\frac{1}{2}$ each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. And I would like to ask the same question as in the above paragraph: what is the probability for the gambler to get to a desired amount of money by waiting long enough? Now let's say the desired amount is just 1 buck, then I'm just asking about the probability that at some $n$ we have $-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-x\geq 0$, which is precisely $1-f(x)$.

The answer to your original question is trivially no function satisfies that functional equation and those two conditions: See that your equation is $f(x) = 2f(x-1) - f(x - 3/2)$, so if you are given the value of $f$ on any interval $I$ of length atleast $3/2$, then that would uniquely determine the value of $f$ for any $x$ larger than that interval. Specifically if $f$ is $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$, then $f$ must be $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, violating condition 2.

@Anon Oh the equation is supposed to hold only for $x>0$ as indicated in the title.

You can solve it in a similar manner then. Basically let $f$ take whatever value on the interval $[0,3/2]$, then it is uniquely determined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Then conditions 1 and 2, will have equivalent conditions on what value $f$ can take on $[0, \frac{3}{2}]$ and this will be the entire solution space for $f$.

@Anon Unless you can actually write down what are the equivalent conditions on what value $f$ can take on $[0,\frac{3}{2}]$, I don't think this observation helps.

You should consider asking a new question since your old question has already been answered.

@BenjaminWang Thank you for the advice. I am new to stackexchange so I'm really unfamiliar with how things work here. My old question is really not that different from the new question that I'm asking: I'm just allowing $\frac{1}{2}$ to be any possible constant $c$. Should I even ask a new question in this case?

The initial position $x$ should be taken in $(1/2)\mathbb{N}$, otherwise the random walk cannot hit $0$. In this case, the random walk stays in $(1/2)\mathbb{Z}$ and stays in $(1/2)\mathbb{N}^*$ before it hits $0$.
Let $r$ be a real number $r$. Observe that for every $n \ge 0$, $$r^{2S_{n+1}^x} = r^{2S_{n}^x}r^{2X_{n+1}}.$$
Since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_n} := \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $S_{n}^x$ is $\mathcal{F_n}$-measurable,
$$\mathbb{E}[r^{2S_{n+1}^x}|\mathcal{F_n}] = r^{2S_{n}^x}\mathbb{E}[r^{2X_{n+1}}] = r^{2S_{n}^x} \times \frac{r^{-1}+r^2}{2}.$$
As a result, the process $(r^{2S_{n}^x})_{n \ge 0}$ is a martingale $(\mathcal{F_n})_{n \ge 0}$ if and only if $r^{-1}+r^2 = 2$, namely if
$r^3-2r+1 = 0$. The polynomial  $r^3-2r+1 = (r-1)(r^2+r-1)$ has a unique root in $]0,1[$, namely $\rho = (-1+\sqrt{5})/2$.
Call $T_x$ the hitting time of $0$ by $(S_{n}^x)_{n \ge 0}$.
Until $T_x$, the martingale $(\rho^{2S_{n}^x})_{n \ge 0}$ stays in $[0,1]$, so optional stopping theorem applies and
$$\rho^{2x} = \mathbb{E}[\rho^{2S_{0}^x}] 
= \mathbb{E}[\rho^{2S_{T_x}^x}] = 1 \mathbb{P}[T_x < +\infty] + 0 \mathbb{P}[T_x = +\infty].$$

Thank you Christophe for your answear! I just realized maybe "hit" was not the correct word to use because I really wanted to allow for $x$ to be any positive real number and the probability that I'm interested in is the probability that $S_n$ stays on the positive half axis, i.e., the probability that $S_n$ doesn't go across the origin from right to left. I have edited the wording of my question so that it's hopefully less confusing now.

The probability for $S^x$ to remain in $~]0,+\infty[$ is the probability for $2S^{\lceil 2x \rceil /2}$ to remain in $\mathbb{N}^*$.

Oh indeed you are correct. This completely solves my question as I initially formulated it. On the other hand I actually wanted to see a solution to $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+1)+f(x-c))$, where $c\in (0,1)$ is some general fixed number. And then I thought probably if one can solve for $c=\frac{1}{2}$, then one can get a solution to any $c$. But as you pointed out, $c=\frac{1}{2}$ is way too special: for irrational $c$, the set of possible values of $S_n$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, and one can no longer restrict to a random walk on a lattice.
